# Keep getting electrified by computer power plug

Tags: power-supply, computer-building, desktop-computer

I recently built a desktop computer, however whenever I move it to a different room for instance, and I accidentally touch the plug pins (UK), I get a quite significant electric shock. Is this a fault with the PSU or is this typical of computers. If it matters I normally hibernate the computer before I move it. Could someone explain why I am getting these shocks?
[Power supply used](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00647L7H8/)

Comment: That isn't normal, even for a fully charged PSU.  Are you sure it's not just a static electricity shock from you moving around between rooms?  If you unplug the PSU form the wall, and then hit the computer's power button to completely drain it, does it still happen?

Comment: @techie007 No it's a pretty big shock

Comment: No; it's. It normal to be shocked by touching the power plug this a new cable?  Of course based on what your using the PSU is basically a cheap knock off at 15 pounds

Comment: @Ramhound the cable itself is old, the PSU only came with the box, I had an older cable lying around

Comment: Try a new cable but again the PSU is very cheap based on the reviews I am not shocked by the experience your having

Comment: If it is completely unplugged from the wall, then the only reason you'd get a shock is if there is stored power in some capacitors. As @techie007 stated, if you press the power button a few times it will drain that residual charge and you should no longer get shocked.

Comment: I happen to have a degree in EE, and I can tell  you for sure capacitors can store a charge for a LONG time after being unplugged.   This is especially true for the larger electrolytic caps you find in PC power supplies.   I was working on an amplifier that had been unplugged for MONTHS and thought I was not in any risk of being shocked.   I was wrong.   I do not know how much voltage there was before, but after I was shocked I used a DMM to measure and there was 600VDC remaining across the two terminals of the capacitor.   Keep in mind, this thing was not plugged in for months.